# Boot from img file

Tags: windows, windows-xp, hard-drive, boot

So from microsoft home page i have downloaded an `.img`  file containing windows xp.

i have burned the img file a `DVD-R` Disk.

besides this i have created an additional drive (called it Win XP) that is suppose to contain my windows xp installation (i have windows 7. at the moment)

Now i want my computer to boot from disk and have therefore in the bios selected Boot from cd drive.

However when i try to boot from the disk, it fails and i am forced to boot windows 7 normally.

I know the information is limited but does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of reasons that might render a CD/DVD unbootable.Some of them are listed [here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000217.htm#02).

In your case, I hope ,you might have burned the image file itself to the DVD-R instead of Burning a bootable ISO image , which might render the DVD-R unbootable.

You can find [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/ss/writeisofecddvd.htm) a step by step guide to burning an ISO File to a Disc.